# Using ToString for Variant variables

Tags: delphi, tostring, delphi-xe7, variant

The following code produces an `EVariantInvalidOpError` exception:

```
var
  i : Variant;
begin
  i := 10;
  ShowMessage(i.ToString());
end;
```

[image: Picture displaying the "Invalid variant operation" exception dialog]

All the following works good but I don't understand why the `ToString` function raises exception for `Variant` type variables:

```
var
  i : Variant;
begin
  i := 10;
  ShowMessage(VarToStr(i));
end;

var
  i : Integer;
begin
  i := 10;
  ShowMessage(i.ToString());
end;
```

Comment: You might notice that `i.ToString`, when `i` is a variant, works just as bad as `i.SendToVoldemort`. This is simply a non-existing method. You are thinking about `TIntegerHelper.ToString` (say), but your `i` isn't an integer, it is a variant. (Indeed, it is not even known at compile time if the variant will hold an integer or not!)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Mmm so the next question would be: why does Delphi allows me using the `ToString` function even if there is no helper implementing such function for the `Variant` type?

Comment: Because variants are special. It's about late binding, dispatch interfaces and stuff like that. I don't know the details, so I'll let someone more knowledgeable answer.

Comment: A variant can contain an [`IDispatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.IDispatch), which uses late binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variants let you store values of various types in them, while the type may be unknown at compile-time. You can write an integer value into single variable of `Variant` type an later overwrite it with string value. Along with the value variant records stores also the [type information](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.TVarType) in it. Among those values some of them are automatically allocated and/or reference counted. The compiler does a lot of stuff behind the scenes when writing or reading the value from `Variant` variable.

Variants of type `varDispatch` get even more special treat from the compiler. `varDispatch` indicates that the value is of type [`IDispatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.IDispatch) (usually, but not necessarily related to Windows [COM technology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal)). Instance of `IDispatch` provides information about its methods and properties via `GetTypeInfoCount` and `GetTypeInfo` methods. You can use its `GetIDsOfNames` method to query the information by name.

Let's answer the question from your comment first:

> Why does Delphi allow me to use the `ToString` function even if there is no helper implementing such function for the `Variant` type?

This is how Delphi implements concept called [late binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding). It allows you to call methods of an object which type is unknown at compile-time. The prerequisite for this to work is that the underlying variant type supports late binding. Delphi has built-in support for late binding of `varDispatch` and `varUnknown` variants as can be seen in procedure `DispInvokeCore` in unit `System.Variants`.

> I don't understand why the `ToString` function raises exception for `Variant` type variables.

As discussed above, in run-time your program tries to invoke `ToString` method on variant value which in your case is of type `varByte`. Since it doesn't support late binding (as well as further ordinal variant types) you get the exception.

To convert variant value to string use [`VarToStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Variants.VarToStr).

Here's a simple example of using late binding with Microsoft Speech API:

```
uses
  Winapi.ActiveX,
  System.Win.ComObj;

var
  Voice: Variant;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    Voice := CreateOleObject('SAPI.SpVoice');
    Voice.Speak('Hello, World!');
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end.
```